# How do I Two WAN Interface and LoadBalance

Tags: network-manager

My Ubuntu server have two public wan interface.I need being able to load balance two wan interfaces.How I do ?

Ubuntu Release: 22.04

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is "Network bonding" or "link aggregation". Take a look at this community wiki article: [Ubuntu Bonding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding)

Be aware that some of the bonding-mode's requires that the switch(s) the server is connected to supports the mode / is  configured correctly too - especially mode 4.

Some modes give load balancing, some fault tolerance and some both.